# jersey is not finding my resource with sub url

Tags: java, spring, http, rest, jersey

I want to have two resources at URLs:  `/apps` and `/apps/runs`.

So, I created resources as shown below. I use `Spring` for object injection. When I use this way, I am getting the `404 error for HTTP get requests` on `/apps/runs`. Am I doing some thing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
@Scope("prototype")
@Path("/apps")
public class ManufacturersResource {

    @GET
    @Produces("application/xml")
    public List<Applications> getApplications() {
        return apps.findAll();
    }
    }

 @Scope("prototype")
 @Path("/apps/runs")
 public class ManufacturersResource {

    @GET
     @Produces("application/xml")
     public List<ApplicationInstances> getApplicationInstances() {
         return appInstances.findAll();
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Jersey won't allow you to have two files share a common prefix, if one is using the prefix as an entire resource url.

So you can move both methods inside the same file, or have /apps be something else like /apps/list